# Is it a good idea to merge [honeycomb] and [android-honeycomb]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Let me keep this simple.

- [honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/honeycomb): 0 questions, no description
- [android-honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-honeycomb): 0 questions, no description

Both are synonyms of [android-3.0-honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-3.0-honeycomb).

Shouldn’t it be its own tag because the user might use 3.2 instead and it would be wrong to use a 3.2 and 3.0 tag on the same question?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Sorry, didn't see that. Shouldn't it be it's own tag because the user might use 3.2 instead and it would be wrong to use a 3.2 and 3.0 tag on the same question?

Comment: [tag:honeycomb] should at least be unsynonymized/disambiguated because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60579106/2821954) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64696721/2821954) are not about Android. Other than that... Android 3.x is pretty much dead.

Comment: If a tag is a synonym of another tag, it *can't* have any questions; they appear under the synonym.